# If selected in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm writing a simple customer handling program.

But I'm stuck at a small function, right now I have a button that once pressed shows the details of whatever customer is chosen in the list (a `JTable`). This button however I only want to be visible once a customer is chosen/marked in the list.

So if no customer is marked the button shouldn't be there.  Can someone point me in the direction of what I should look at?

Answer (score 3):

```
// item has been selected in table..
button.setVisible(true);
```

But it might be better to do..

```
// item has been selected in table..
button.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I like the whole "Houdini button" idea. Instead, as [@Andrew Thompson stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668189/if-selected-in-jtable/8668248#8668248), toggle the button's "enabled" state. Also, in order to notify the button of selection events, it will need to [listen for selection events](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/SelEvent.html).